# How to execute 2 coroutines in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

I cannot get two coroutines to execute in parallel in my Python 3.6 program. Here is an example:

```
import asyncio, time

def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(start_coros())


async def start_coros():
    await coro1()
    await coro2()


async def coro1():
    print("coro1")
    time.sleep(3000)


async def coro2():
    print("coro2 - we want to get here")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As you can see, the first coroutine gets executed first but the second does not run concurrently.

Can you please give me a hint as to how to run them both simultaneously?

Thanks kindly in advance for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run two coroutines "in parallel", create Tasks:

```
async def start_coros():
    # ensure_future -> create_task in Python 3.7
    tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(coro()) for coro in (coro1, coro2)]
    await asyncio.wait(tasks)
```

However there is a huge problem in `coro1`. `asyncio` is based on cooperative scheduling. Only one coroutine can run at a time. A scheduler switches between coroutines, but that can happen only when the running coroutine awaits something. If a coroutine spends too much time between `awaits`, the program appears not responsive. So avoid `time.sleep()`!

```
async def coro1():
    print("coro1")
    await asyncio.sleep(3000)
```

Comment: Is there a way for a coroutine to deliberately 'yield' to the scheduler?

Comment: @VPfB Thanks for the answer. I need to pass different parameters to `coro1` and `coro2`. How do I achieve this? Suppose `coro1` is defined as `def coro1(word): print(word)` and `coro2` is defined as `def coro2(number): print(number)`, then how would `tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(coro()) for coro in (coro1, coro2)]` look like in that case?

Comment: @quamrana Yes, this is the command for it: `await asyncio.sleep(0)`

Comment: @JeniaIvanov Try this: `tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(coro) for coro in (coro1(arg1), coro2(arg2))]`, or do not use a comprehension and just make a simple list of tasks.