# Can I use await on multiple functions at once?

Tags: python

I'm learning about the magic of concurrency in python and I have a script that I have been using await in(via fastapi's framework).

I need to get multiple data from my database and do something like:

```
DBresults1 = await db_conn.fetch_rows(query_statement1)
DBresults2 = await db_conn.fetch_rows(query_statement2)
DBresults3 = await db_conn.fetch_rows(query_statement3)
#then on to processing...
```

The problem is my awaits are causing my code to run sequentially which is getting to be slow.

Is there a way to have my 3 queries(or any function call for that matter) to run without await but await until the entire group is done so it can execute concurrently?

Comment: Use [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute 2 coroutines in Python 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62176212/how-to-execute-2-coroutines-in-python-3-6)

Comment: @enzo that's kind of helpful thank you. I cannot nest my queries into a for loop, should I nest a command like len(DBresults1) and then make that await to get the above commands execute concurrently?

Comment: I'm not sure whether that link goes over it and I'm not too familiar with async, however, I believe you are looking to [create tasks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task)?

Comment: This question is answered [by the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently).

Comment: You can use threading or multiprocessing. The difference is threading will be on one cpu core and multiprocessing can use many. I would use something like threading and then a .join command

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `gather` to await multiple tasks non-sequentially. You mentioned FastAPI, this example might help. It does a 3 second task and a 2 second task in ~3 seconds total. Although the first task takes longer, gather will give you results in the order you list them, not the order they complete.

For this to work, the long running part needs to be actual awaitable IO (simulated with `asyncio.sleep` here) not CPU bound work.

If you run this in a terminal, then call `GET localhost:8080` from Postman (or whatever is convenient for you) you'll see what's happening in the logs.

```
import logging
import asyncio
import time
from fastapi import FastAPI

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format="%(levelname)-9s %(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(message)s")
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)

app = FastAPI()

async def takes_three():
    LOGGER.info("will sleep for 3s...")
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    LOGGER.info("takes_three awake!")
    return "takes_three done"

async def takes_two():
    LOGGER.info("will sleep for 2s...")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    LOGGER.info("takes_two awake!")
    return "takes_two done"


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    start_time = time.time()
    LOGGER.info("starting...")
    results = await asyncio.gather(*[takes_three(), takes_two()])
    duration = time.time() - start_time
    LOGGER.info(f"results: {results} after {duration:.2f}")
    return f"finished after {duration:.2f}s!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8080)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `asyncio.wait` like in example below

```
async def get_suggest(entity, ids, company_id):
     ...
     return ...


jobs = []
for entity, ids, in dict(data.filters).items():
    jobs.append(get_suggest(entity, ids, company_id))

result = {}
done, _ = await asyncio.wait(jobs)
for job in done:
     values, entity = job.result()
     result[entity] = values
```